Possible to track sitewide voting progress over time?
With regard to this meta question, is it possible to see the number of votes cast, over time (per day) for Bitcoin.SE?
I think a nice overlay to this graph would be the #of questions or answers that have been created or updated in the past 3 days.

Such statistics are available to both site moderators and StackExchange staff, though not typically to the general public. We have, on occasion, been given permission to release tidbits of information but in general such statistics are not made public beyond the values posted on our Area51 proposal page.
Suffice it to say that we know what our site's traffic and interaction levels look like and are always actively pushing the community to fill in the weak spots, which right now is questions asked per day.
